# How can I store a DateTime::Duration object in my DBI::Class model on a MySQL database?

Tags: perl, datetime, dbix-class

I currently use the [DBIx::Class::InflateColumn::DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/~frew/DBIx-Class-0.08123/lib/DBIx/Class/InflateColumn/DateTime.pm) plugin to inflate my date columns to DateTime objects and deflate my DateTime objects to MySQL date values.

I want to store the age of an individual (I cannot use DOB) and for this the years, months or days values may be 0. Therefore I am using a DateTime::Duration object. Thing is the plugin will fail if the value is not a valid date (and 0020-08-00 is not valid). Can I use the plugin, do I have to write my own or is there another way?

(BTW MySQL does allow such values - I am not concerned if it is 'invalid' - it works for what I need and I am not planning to change my RDBMS.)

Comment: Thinking about it some more, and discussing on #dbix-class, it looks like I need a better serializer than a datetime column. I'm looking at using DateTime::Format::Duration::XSD and writing my own inflatecolumn component based on that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended writing my own InflateColumn module. You can find it [on the CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/~cubabit/DBIx-Class-InflateColumn-DateTime-Duration-0.01002/lib/DBIx/Class/InflateColumn/DateTime/Duration.pm)